# Model is not finding a GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

The problem that I am facing is that my Model in my `foreach` is throwing error "`foreach` statement cannot operate on variables of type Mileage does not contain a public instance definition for `GetEnumerator`"

I have tried both `IEnumerator<> IEnumerable<>` and `List<>` but none of those supposed fixes have resolved my issue.

**This is my Model**

```
public partial class Mileage
    {
        public int RowIndex { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpMonthYr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TripType { get; set; }
        public string MileageIndex { get; set; }
        public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TravelDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is my Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var results = db.database.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM database").ToList();
            return View(results);
        }
```

**This is my View**

```
@model IEnumerator<Database.Models.Mileage>
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <tr id="">

      </tr>
   }
</tbody>
```

Comment: It's not `IEnumerator`, it should be `IEnumerable`. Closing this as a typo.

Comment: @DavidG, "*I have tried both `IEnumerator<>` `IEnumerable<>` and `List<>` but none of those supposed fixes have resolved my issue.*"

Comment: I have done this as a IEnumerable and it still gives me the same error

Comment: What type is `results`?

Comment: @canton7 Yes, but either I'm right or OP isn't showing us their actual code. Which one do you think it is?

Comment: results is a list

Comment: it might be that when you updated the model of the Razor view from IEnumerator to IEnumerable that Visual Studio failed to recognize this. Use IEnumerable and just try debugging the app--it should work--also try restarting Visual Studio to get it to see the updated IEnumerable correctly

Comment: @DominikWillaford but a list of what type?

Comment: @egnomerator That seemed to fix this issue. I never heard of Visual studio needing a restart if it doesn't recognize something like that, but thank you!

Comment: Only thing is that when I do that then my referrences to ExpMonthYr within my view can't be found.

Comment: @Magnetron I'm sorry I guess I'm not following what you are asking its just a generic list if you need to know more information let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured I would submit my comment as an answer--I've seen this behavior enough that I think this could be helpful.

It might be that when you updated the model of the Razor view from `IEnumerator` to `IEnumerable` that Visual Studio failed to recognize this change.

So, use `IEnumerable` like this (as I think you already correctly tried)

```
@model IEnumerable<Database.Models.Mileage>
```

then just try debugging the app, and it should work, also try restarting Visual Studio and Razor IntelliSense should correctly recognize the use of `IEnumerable`